# Remove styling on a center tag

Tags: html

I am working with a system that outputs the following syntax (which I can't change)

```
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <center>
      [The page contents]
    </center>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to nullify the formatting on the `<center>` element as it is messing with my responsive layout. Any ideas how to nullify the style on this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you need to do, but you can use css on the `center` element like so:

```
center {
    text-align: left;
}
```

or maybe:

```
center {
    float: left;
}
```

Try out some different things and see what works best.

Comment: This is was I was doing, but it wasn't working. Turns out there was some other crap HTML/CSS in the templates that was messing with the layout. Thanks for letting me know I was not crazy! Figured out how to work around all the issues with with the predefined layout now!

Answer (score 2):

What about using jQuery to rewrite the content of the  after-the-fact?  Something like:

```
$(".page").replaceWith($(".page center").contents());
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/5fuBm/1/

Comment: I like the brute force approach here. Fighting fire with fire.